# Odoo : inputing employee based on department_id, one2many domain

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

from this picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSxPV.jpg)

when i click on the add new item, i want employee list that show up is only employees 
from the selected department, in the pict case is "IT" department. iam using odoo v8

ive tried this in my o2m field :

```
class overtime(models.Model):
    _name = 'overtime.overtime'

    department_id = fields.Many2one('hr.department', string='Department', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
    employee_ids = fields.One2many('overtime.overtime_details', 'overtime_id', string="Employee", 
                                domain="[('hr.employee.department_id', '=', department_id)]")


class overtime_details(models.Model):
    _name='overtime.overtime_details'

    nik = fields.Char('NIK', size=250, required=True)
    overtime_id = fields.Many2one('overtime.overtime', string="Overtime", ondelete='cascade')
    job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job', string="Position")
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', "Employee", required=True, select=True)
```

and got error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 544, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 581, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 317, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 314, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 810, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 410, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3148, in read
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3183, in read
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3370, in _read_from_database
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\osv\fields.py", line 774, in get
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

here is the xml :

```
   <record id="overtime_form1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">overtime_form1</field>
            <field name="model">overtime.overtime</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Overtime Request Form">
                  <sheet>
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <label for="code" class="oe_edit_only"
                            string="Overtime Code" />
                        <h1>
                            <field name="code" />
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <field name="department_id"/>
                        <label string="Duration"/>
                        <div>
                            <group col="5">
                                <field name="start_date" class="oe_inline"/>
                                <label string="-" class="oe_inline"/>
                                <field name="end_date" class="oe_inline"/>
                            </group>
                            </div>
                            <field name="total_overtime"/>
                            <field name="overtime_bonus"/>
                            <field name="reason"/>  
                        </group>
                        <notebook>
                            <page string="Employees">
                                <field name="employee_ids" >
                                    <tree string="Employees" editable="bottom">
                                        <field name="nik"/>
                                        <field name="employee_id"/>
                                        <field name="job_id"/>
                                    </tree>
                                </field>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

thanks before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using **parent.department_id**.

```
<notebook>
<page string="Employees">
    <field name="employee_ids" >
        <tree string="Employees" editable="bottom">
            <field name="nik"/>
            <field name="employee_id" domain="[('department_id', '=',parent.department_id)]" />
            <field name="job_id"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</page>
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add a related field to the `overtime.overtime_details` model to identify the `department_id` like this:

```
department_id = fields.Many2one(related="overtime_id.department_id", store=False)
```

Then, in the xml view now you can filter the `employee_id` list by the `department_id` in the tree of the `employee_ids` field:

```
<notebook>
<page string="Employees">
    <field name="employee_ids" >
        <tree string="Employees" editable="bottom">
            <field name="department_id" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="nik"/>
            <field name="employee_id" domain="[('department_id', '=', department_id)]" />
            <field name="job_id"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</page>
</notebook>
```

Comment: the domain did work properly, but the domain still gives `false` value. so the `employee_id` that shown up just the ones with `false` value in its `department_id`, even i have changed the `department_id` in the parent model. i want to know bout how this way works, even ive found out the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the employees in `employee_id` with `domain`:

```xml
<notebook>
    <page string="Employees">
        <field name="employee_ids" >
            <tree string="Employees" editable="bottom">
                <field name="nik"/>
                <field name="employee_id" domain="[('department_id', '=', department_id)]" />
                <field name="job_id"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Comment: it doesnt work, should i remove the "editable="bottom" ? thanks for ur answers btw

Comment: No sorry it won't work. I did'nt read your code well. I will edit my answer.

Comment: still doesnt work it says `"Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'department_id' is not defined"`