# Onchange triggered but didnt fill the fields with the values on the view (Odoo)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I've made an `onchange` function, the goal of which is to autofill the values on the notebook sheet view.

My function was working properly but it didn't fill the field on the view.

What should i do to achieve this?

this was what i got from pdb:

[image]

and that was the value i want but it didnt fill the field on the view

and here is the py :

```py
@api.multi
@api.model
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def onchange_lines(self):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    if self.employee_id:
        check = self.env['hr.employee'].sudo().search([('id','=',self.employee_id.id)])
        for empy in check:
            if empy.id:
                res = {}
                vals = []
                if not empy:
                    vals.
                    res.update({'self.job_id':'', 'self.nik':''})
                else:
                    vals.append({'self.job_id':empy.job_id, 'self.nik':empy.identification_id})
                    res.update(vals)
            return res
```

and here is the xml for the fields :

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<notebook>
    <page string="Employees">
        <field name="employee_ids">
            <tree string="Employees" editable="bottom">
                <field name="nik"/>
                <field name="employee_id"/>
                <field name="job_id"/>
                <field name="ovrtm"/>
                <field name="ttalmtp"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In odoo new api of onchange you can directly assign value in record-set object.

You can follow below code.

```
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def onchange_lines(self):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    if self.employee_id:
        check = self.env['hr.employee'].sudo().search([('id','=',self.employee_id.id)])
        for empy in check:
            if empy.id:
                res = {}
                vals = []
                if not empy:
                    self.job_id=False
                    self.nik=False
                else:
                    self.job_id=empy.job_id
                    self.nik=empy.identification_id
```

This may help you.

Comment: it works thanks, and could you see my other question about domain ? here is the link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666521/odoo-inputing-employee-based-on-department-id-one2many-domain thanks in advance